# Help with System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, system.net.mail

I'm trying to send emails from my webpage, so I have tried this:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Dim mSmtpClient As SmtpClient
Dim MMsg As MailMessage

Sub SendEmail()
        MMsg = New MailMessage()

        MMsg.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
        MMsg.To.Add(txtTo.Text)

        MMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        MMsg.Body = txtBody.Text

        MMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
        MMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

        mSmtpClient = New SmtpClient("host_name_goes_here")
        mSmtpClient.Send(MMsg)
End Sub
```

But this is not working.  I keep getting the following error:

```
Type 'SmtpClient' is not defined.

Line 7: Dim mSmtpClient As SmtpClient
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I have looked at:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

But can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: use dim mSmtpClient  as new SmtpClient

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri, I've just tried that and I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Changing the point when the class is created won't make any difference in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is new code...

```
Dim mSmtpClient As New SmtpClient
Dim MMsg As New MailMessage

Sub SendEmail()
    MMsg = New MailMessage()

    MMsg.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
    MMsg.To.Add(txtTo.Text)

    MMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
    MMsg.Body = txtBody.Text

    MMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
    MMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

    mSmtpClient = New SmtpClient("host_name_goes_here")
    mSmtpClient.Send(MMsg)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be in a container, like a class or a module. So try this:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

public module mymail

    Dim mSmtpClient As SmtpClient
    Dim MMsg As MailMessage

    Sub SendEmail()
        MMsg = New MailMessage()

        MMsg.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
        MMsg.To.Add(txtTo.Text)

        MMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        MMsg.Body = txtBody.Text

        MMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
        MMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

        mSmtpClient = New SmtpClient("host_name_goes_here")
        mSmtpClient.Send(MMsg)
    End Sub
end module
```

You could also use a class if you wanted.

Simon